# Catching the output of scontrol show job ID with python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, slurm

I'm trying to return the output of the slurm command `scontrol show job ID` where `ID` is the ID number of the slurm job, to python as a string. I'm trying to use python's `subprocess` command by trying

```
x = subprocess.check_output("scontrol show job 62988265")
```

However this results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scontrol show job 62988265': 'scontrol show job 62988265'
```

What am I missing? I'm confused as to what the command and argument are in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check_output` method expects a list of parameters, not a string ;  it will not parse and tokenise the string hence looking for a single executable named `scontrol show job 33087539`.

```
$ python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Apr  5 2021, 11:09:18)
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> x = subprocess.check_output("scontrol show job 33087539")
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scontrol show job 33087539'
```

Use the `split` method like this:

```
>>> x = subprocess.check_output("scontrol show job 33087539".split())
>>> print(x)
b'JobId= 33087539 JobName=bash\n
[...]
```